# css problem with height

Tags: html, css

I've got a div that contains an unordered list that gets updated by an ajax query. It's used for a livesearch.

Now I have this problem that when I set the height of the div to a fixed height (let's say 200) that the results are shown as they should. But when I don't set the height, or set it to auto, the div has a height of 0 when the searchresults are added to the ul.

I think this has something to do with the ajaxquery and the browser not recognizing the new height, but I don't know how to set it the right way.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe add the code you are using to populate the ul.  There may be an issue there.

Comment: I think you might need to post some HTML / CSS.

Comment: What do you mean "div has a height of 0"? How do you measure it? What exactly do you see? Does the `div` have absolute position or floating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding some dummy content statically on the html page and see if the height is still 0. If it is then you have a CSS issue. Most probably the contents of the div (list) are absolute positioned so the parent div cannot know the list's height.

Comment: When I add dummycontent the div is also not shown :S I suppose this must be a css problem then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding adding a min-height to the div containing the ul.

```
min-height: whatever-you-want-minimum-height;
```